# Can't attach geth or curl RPC to geth

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I have built go-ethereum from source and I'm running on Ubuntu in a Docker container. I can run geth commands from the command line just fine, but I'm having trouble attaching to it or curling RPCalls to it.

For example:

```
nohup geth --verbosity 0 --rpc import /home/myvbo/cloudwallets/serverbinaries/blockchainTo1463224 &
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' localhost:8545
geth attach http://localhost:8545
```

The error message for the curl is `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8545: Connection refused`

The error message for the attach is `Fatal: Unable to attach to geth node - Invalid endpoint`

What am I missing?  Have I not completely configured geth for RPC?

Comment: Can you check if geth is running inside docker? It may failed to start. As a test you may try to attach using ipc.If geth is running perhaps some other program is using port 8545, use netstat -nlp to find the open ports.

Comment: I am starting with the simplest case, running the docker container to start  a shell, then running geth and curl from the command line, inside the container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you start Geth it may take some seconds for it to finish booting. Only after finishing the startup will the HTTP/IPC/WS endpoints be opened, so you'll need to wait for that to happen before you can send requests to it.

Edit: Do note, Geth has a lot of administrative subcommands (e.g. account, import, upgradedb, etc) which only execute some predefined functionality and then terminate. They do not start a node, so there's nothing to connect to.

Comment: I thought that this might be the case as well, but I get the same result if I wait a minute, several minutes, or ten minutes.  Your point does give me an idea, however; as I am launching geth with parameters to import a saved blockchain, is it possible that the endpoints don't get opened until the import finishes?

Comment: Ahh, now I see. Running `import` is a separate command that just loads a blockchain and then exists. It doesn't start geth or anything related to it.

Comment: I just tried mining after the import completes, and then curling the same POST.  Geth is still mining as I write this, and still refusing the connection.

Comment: I tried the attach without an endpoint (as in 'geth attach') and I get a different error message: 'Fatal: Unable to attach to geth node - dial unix /root/.ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory'    This persists even after applying chown and chmod to the parent of geth.ipc so something larger appears to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

What I needed to was

1. Wait until the import had completed
2. Wait a few minutes after I ran geth with --rpc to download the rest of the blockchain.

That's it.  I just needed to wait twice.  Thank you Péter!

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick on the left if this is what solved your problem.