# How can I get eth console?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I'm new to ethereum.

I downloaded eth, geth, and mix from https://www.ethereum.org/cli, but I can't find ethconsole.exe file in the zip file.

The only executable in the zip file is eth.exe. I tried 'eth.exe console' command but did not work.

How can I run eth console with eth.exe file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need both Eth and Geth? They're two seperate clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start syncing the blockchain you can use the command `geth fast`. As you can see the screen will keep track of the sync as it is progressing. At any time you can cancel the sync and reconnect where you left off. The second time you reconnect use the command `geth --verbosity 0 --fast console`. Verbosity is a flag which controls how much output comes back from the client, which you can set to 0. Type `web3` to see the full list of available methods.

Also in a seperate window you can attach to the running chain using `geth attach`. More info about `attach` here: [Can't attach geth or curl RPC to geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5732/cant-attach-geth-or-curl-rpc-to-geth)

Comment: So there is no eth console? Only geth console is available?